# MorphologicalPerimeter[] unstable behaviour with increasing threshold values

Tags: image-processing, segmentation

I have a [PET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positron_emission_tomography) image represented as a list of lists of grey value intensities. [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25202446/filteredData.mat) you can find the file in a "MAT" format (you can import it like: `filteredData = Flatten[#,1]&@Import["filteredData.mat", "MAT"];`).

I am using `MorphologicalPerimeter[]` to implement a threshold based simple image segmentation. My code looks like this:

```
Manipulate[
 ImageCompose[
  ArrayPlot@filteredData, {
   MorphologicalPerimeter[ArrayPlot@filteredData,
    actThreshPercent*Max@filteredData/100],
   0.2
   }
  ],
 {actThreshPercent, 1, 100, 1}
 ]
```

For threshold = 40:

[image]

If I increase the threshold, the perimeter of the curve that is returned by `MorphologicalPerimeter[]` becomes smaller then larger and so on. Shouldn't it be steadily smaller as the threshold increases ?

For threshold = 55:

[image]

Specs: Mathematica 11, Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are applying `MorphologicalPerimeter` to the `ArrayPlot` (and not just the data within the plot). Use `Image` instead:

```
Manipulate[MorphologicalPerimeter[Image[filteredData, ImageSize -> 500], 
  tau*Max@filteredData/100.], {tau, 1, 100}]
```

and you will see the perimeter shrinks monotonically as you increase the threshold parameter.

There are lots of ways to superimpose images. First, turn the data into an image

```
img = ColorNegate[Image[filteredData, ImageSize -> 500] // ImageAdjust]
```

then use `ImageMultiply`

```
Manipulate[ImageMultiply[img, ColorNegate@
   MorphologicalPerimeter[Image[filteredData, ImageSize -> 500], 
    tau*Max@filteredData/100.]], {tau, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: Thanks bill. How could I superimpose the resultant image to my original one?